# How can I output the translated contents from alert() in angular-gettext?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to translate the alert. I used `angular-gettext`;

How can I output the translated contents from `alert()` in `angular-gettext`?
example for

```
swal("", "<span translate>mobile.ver.send</span>");
```

or

```
alert("", "<span translate>mobile.ver.send</span>");
```

Currently it works well in html.

```
<span translate>mobile.ver.send</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert(gettext(mobile.ver.send));
```

You can read more here: https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/annotate-js/